# Taking the Laplace Transform of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(nT)\delta(t-nT)$.

Tags: proof-verification, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

> I am trying to show that $$\mathcal{L}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(nT)\delta(t-nT)\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)z^{-n},$$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function. Note tht $f(nT)$ and $f(n)$ **do not** denote the same function.

So far, I have shown that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(nT)\delta(t-nT)\right)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(nT)\delta(t-nT)\right) dt \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(nT)\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\delta(t-nT) \ dt \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(nT)\mathcal{L}\left(\delta(t-nT)\right) \ dt \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(nT)e^{-snT} \tag{1}.
\end{align}
A hint on further progression would be appreciated. I do not require a full result.

Update:
Can we assume that $f(n)=f(nT)$ as $T$ denotes the period?

Comment: As you see if $T\ne 1$ then your yellow formula isn't correct. Otherwise it is with $z = e^{-s}$. Also note the convolution theorem gives $F \ast \frac{1}{1-e^{-s}}$ as another expression for the Laplace transform.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand. Are you saying the substitution $z=e^{-s}$ would work? I don't understand if what I've done so far is correct and if $f(n)=f(nT)$.

Comment: I'm saying in the context of the Z-transform then $z = e^{-s}$ by definition. The Z-transform is the Laplace transform of sequences, equivalently of distributions of the form $\sum_n c(n)\delta(t-n)$

Comment: What if we made a substitution $\bar{n}=nT$ to $(1)$. Then $z^{\bar{n}}=e^{-s\bar{n}}$. Would this prove the equation in yellow?

Comment: Sure. First of all $\int_0^\infty g(t) \delta(t-a) dt = g(a)$ for $g$ continuous and $a > 0$ by definition, that is one less step is your computation. For $a = 0$ you have a problem because $g(t) 1_{t > 0}$ isn't continuous at $0$, you need to understand the Laplace transform isn't $\int_0^\infty h(t) e^{-st}dt$ but $\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t) e^{-st}dt$ for $h$ supported on $t > c$ for some $c$. Finally you need to clarify that integrals/series need some assumptions on the convergence, absolute convergence being easier, and it is what you need to exchange $\sum$ and $\int$

Comment: @reuns Sorry for the late reply. In your first comment, you said that "if $T≠1$
then your yellow formula isn't correct". Does this mean that we can assume $T=1$?

Answer (score 1):

The steps you have taken are correct. As you have stated, the function $f$ on the right hand side (as $f(n)$) is not the same function $f$ on the left hand side (as $f(nT)$). To be slightly more clear, let us define $f[n] := f(nT)$ (with square brackets) and $z := e^{sT}$ then
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(nT) e^{-snT} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f[n] (e^{sT})^{-n} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f[n] z^{-n}. \\
\end{align}

This identity is mainly used in sampling continuous time signals with $T$ being the sampling period (this may be different from the period of the $f$, if $f$ is periodic). The $f[.]$ is referred to as the discrete-time sample. For further information, you may refer to the following question from Signal Processing Stack Exchange: [sampling with Laplace Transform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40433/laplace-transform-of-product-of-signal-and-impulse-train).